# How to add programs in context menu on desktop at one context name?

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, regedit

Hello I'm searching for answer how to put programs (not program) in context menu of desktop at one context name?

Example:
I want to create new context name which can be extendable to put inside more programs. That is like "New" or "View" that show as more options after using it.

Here is what i tried (and is working when you want to put one program to desktop):

1. I created in registry "New Folder" with name of some programs (i.e. "notepad") inside of  this location HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\
2. Inside of new created folder ("notepad") i put one more time "New Folder" and name it "command" (must be same name)
3. Inside of "command" at string ("Default") put the location through notepad ("C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe")

-> and now when you click right mouse button on desktop will see new context text with name "notepad" what will of course open notepad if you use them

Well what i'm searching for is to find solution of how to make context name which will offer as to use more that one programs, do you have any solution?

O.S. win 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\MyMenu]
"MUIVerb"="&My Menu"
"SubCommands"="MyMenu.mycmd1;MyMenu.mycmd2;MyMenu.mycmd3"
"Icon"="shell32.dll,43"
"Position"="Bottom"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\MyMenu.mycmd1]
@="&Paint"
"Icon"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\Mspaint.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\MyMenu.mycmd1\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\Mspaint.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\MyMenu.mycmd2]
@="&Notepad"
"icon"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\Notepad.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\MyMenu.mycmd2\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\Notepad.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\MyMenu.mycmd3]
@="&Calculator"
"Icon"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\Calc.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\MyMenu.mycmd3\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\Calc.exe"
```

The above saved as a .REG file and imported into the registry will result in the following being added to the Desktop's context menu only:

[image: 1]
Modify as required and enjoy. :)

Comment: thank you very much Karan you save me lot of time it works perfect, where do you find those information, i search on google but didn't find anything similar

Comment: Aww, no upvote? :( j/k ;) As for the source of the info., lots of stuff read on the net over the years as well as hours of tinkering in the registry myself with a recent backup always on hand.

Comment: i will like to upvote but can't cause i don't have enough reputation (minimal is 15) ... if you vote up on question that will allow me to accept you answere and vote up (but don't warry when i get some reputtion will remeber to vote up) .. thnx one more time

Comment: Hah, don't worry about it, I was just kidding. :) There's no pressure here on anyone to accept or upvote any answer. Glad I could help. Cheers!

Comment: man i appreciate your work and i'm searching for some answers on this forum to get more reputation and be for sure that will accept and up your answare (you help me a lot )

Comment: Like I said, don't worry about it. Upvotes and downvotes happen as a matter of course, and if you hang around long enough and provide useful answers your rep's bound to go up. So if you can just pass it along and help someone else here. :)