# How to organize Windows XP Explorer context menu items?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, context-menu

I understand fairly well how to create new commands for specific file types on Windows XP -- either through the Registry or editing the File Types on the Windows Explorer; in those cases, I tend to copy from existing options and adapt them.

However, I have not yet found a convincing way to reliably organize **existing** context menu items to unclutter an extensive Explorer context menu. For example, I'd like to be able to create a menu option "*Source control...*" where I could move existing context menu items for different SCMs installed on the system (Git, SVN, Mercurial).

I've tried some freeware software, but they didn't provide obvious solutions and some required the constant execution of a background process. Some have unusual interfaces, others do little more than hiding options, etc. So, some Regedit wizardry would probably be the desired implementation, although I'm willing to read alternative solutions.

Comment: I don't quite remember how much of this is supported in XP, but in Win7+ you can [create cascading menus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#static_cascading), as I demonstrated in my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/509892/138343). However, adding your own entries is far easier than tracking down and moving entries for existing context menu handlers (plus who knows what might break on doing that).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try ShellExView or ShellMenu. Both allow you to edit the context menu. They aren't pretty but they do work. P.S. I too wish there was a tool to organize and make the context menu more efficient to use.