# How to get customizable right click menu for Windows 7 desktop?

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-interface, desktop-customization

99 percent of a time I am using some flavor of Unix on my desktop with Fluxbox as window manager of choice.
I want to make remaining 1 percent I spent on Windows as painless a possible.
I really love customizable desktop context menu in Fluxbox and I would love
to have it on Windows.

I want to **completely** replace standard desktop context menu in Windows 7
and I am looking for an application that will handle this.

I am not interested in registry hacking.
In the past I used *bb4win* and *bblean* and their derivatives but I consider them lacking in stability and functionality so I resent them too.

Ideally, the program I am looking for would allow me to graphically define multilevel menu,
where single menu action could be starting a program (like running a Web Browser) or performing standard Windows action (like locking a screen or shutting down the system).

I am only interested in replacing right click menu for desktop, I do not care for right click menu in folders.

Thank you for your suggestions.

**Edit**

Now I see I was not specific enough.
One thing I require is complete freedom in deciding what items are available at each level
of menu, also at top level, so ability to put arbitrary items in submenu of main menu is not enough, I want also to choose members of main menu.

Acceptable solution would be program like one of *bb4win* or *bblean* **but** as simple and as non-intrusive as possible. Both *bb4win* and *bblean* are very buggy and quite clunky,
so something way more polished than those two would be required.

I did not mention that, and that is my bad, I want a free (as in "free beer") solution.

Thank you, and sorry for the noise.

Comment: I like your idea. But I don't think its possible :( I have never seen it done on un-hacked Windows. The same boring square box for the last 16 years of my life...

Comment: Shame you're not interested in registry hacking when it's so much fun! :) If you were, my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/509892/138343) would have helped you to easily add programs/commands of your choice to a sub-menu in the Desktop's context menu.

Answer (score 2):

To do:
A "right click menu added utility"
http://www.askvg.com/right-click-context-menu-adder-free-utility-to-add-program-shortcut-in-windows-7-desktop-context-menu/
There is a List of other utilities here [Edit right-click context menus in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/209556/edit-right-click-context-menus-in-windows-7)
A utility like this one could add stuff to the right click menu, although registry adding some things really would not be that hard. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\

And to Undo:
AutoRuns http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx
To remove a Lot of things from the context menu now, this would be a good tool.
You could save a configuration with this providing a backup method, although I would also be backing up the whole system disk as a total means of recoverability.

Then knowing how to batch some, `rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState` and getting a few utility items, when needed for the rest. mabey AutoHotKey if you really had something special to have to accomplish like locating windows, sending keys, and IDing things.

There might be better tools out there, and there will alway be some limitations due to hard coded things.

Rarely Items in the context menu have been known to completly lock up the computer, And you can't know for a fact what MS might do, or some program addition that that could cause that. Context menu items, also Slow down getting to the right click as more junk is added there.

The items in the context menu are accessed some way when the menu comes up, and doing this perfect and not changing it or the rest of the system Under it when it is there could be critical.

I would not do it. They have had enough problems there, without me adding to them.  Any fully seperated program, drag and drop box, toolbar with menus, hotkeys , hot corners, or anything could be way more foolproof and stable in bad situations.

Comment: I tried tool from your first link before, it crashes immediately after start on my machine. Otherwise that could be at least partial solution for my problem. And yes, completely separated program would be solution for me, like I said, I used _bb4win_ and _bblean_ before, exactly to achieve this, but they suck on stability so I no longer use them.

Comment: I use autohide toolbars, and have (after setup) access to: A) every setup item in the whole control pannel including a few that are down a few clicks.  B) access to about 60 programs  C) access to every partition and external on my system  D) every boot item, log off monitor off etc. In One Sweep and one click.   This particular toobar setup could also be a window small or large on the desktop have any number of menu items , and even do cute transparency stuff, but I do not use any of those features.  I was Trained/Ingrained into Toolbars back in XP, and could not live without them any more.

Answer (score 2):

FileMenu Tools (http://www.lopesoft.com/en/filemenutools) is a gui application that might get you most of the way. It has pretty good options in terms of adding menu items (and you can do anything you can run from the command line), and it can let you hide a number of application specific menu items, but it might not get you everything.

Comment: I cannot find the way to edit main desktop menu with this software, but thank you never the less for link to nice utility.

Comment: You mean the menu when you right click on the desktop? On my copy of win7, when I right click on the desktop I get the FileMenu Tools submenu, and other commands I've added to be active for Files, Folders and Drives under Commands of FileMenu Tools.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Right Click Enhancer Professional. There is demo version available at http://rbsoft.org/downloads/right-click-enhancer. There is 4 shortcuts limit, but you can buy full version for $9.99 if you like it. It has all the features like export functionality, reordering of right click entries in sub menu, creating sub menus.

Comment: According to comments in [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/209810/173394), it is not safe to install this software.

Comment: Right Click Enhancer installer version contains babylon browser toolbar but portable version is free of ads. There is also a paid version which didn't contain ads in installer and portable version.